# What is wrong with my structure with stack and stock list program?

Tags: c++

In the program I need a structure with a stack, and list. Opportunities to add a product, display a list of products, delete the last product.
I wrote this program, but I get a huge amount of errors.
Can you tell me what is wrong with my program?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Stack
{
    int* stack;
    int size = 0;
    int Capasity = 0;
    Stack() {}
    Stack(int aCapasity)
    {
        stack = new int[aCapasity];
        Capasity = aCapasity;
    }
    ~Stack()
    {
        delete stack;
    }
    bool push(int var)
    {
        if (size < Capasity)
        {
            stack[size] = var;
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error, Size == Capasity, use Stack(N) to resize stack");
            return false;
        }
    }
    int pop()
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            size--;
            return stack[size];
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error, No elements");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    int peek()
    {
        if (size > 0)
            return stack[size - 1];
        else
        {
            printf("Error, No elements");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    void showStack()
    {
        int size_temp = size;
        for (; size > 0; size--)
        {
            printf("%d ", stack[size - 1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        size = size_temp;
    }
};

struct Node
{
    char* name = new char[6];
    float sumary;
    int amount;
    Node(char* name, float sumary, int amount) :name(name), sumary(sumary), amount(amount)
    {
    }
    Node() {}
};

int main()
{
    int command;
    stack<Node> node;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Input command:\n 1 - add,\n 2 - delete last,\n 3 - show all,\n 4 - exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        switch (command)
        {
        case 1:
            char name[6];
            float sumary;
            int amount;
            printf("Enter name: ");
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("Enter sumary: ");
            scanf("%f", &sumary);
            printf("Enter amount: ");
            scanf("%d", &amount);
            node.push(Node(name, sumary, amount));
            break;
        case 2:
            node.pop();
            printf("The last have been deleted");
            break;
        case 3:
            while (!example.empty())
            {
                Node temp = example.top();
                example.pop();
                cout << temp.name << " " << temp.sumary << " " << temp.amount << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Wrong command...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can’t even show errors here, there are too many of them.

Comment: Are you compiling this as C or C++? If you're compiling as C, as your tag suggests, then I can understand there being a lot fo errors.

Comment: This code is not C, it is C++. ~Stack() is a destructor. In linux, e.g., if you want to compile C++, use g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: You have not included the required header files. Also, there is no `example` variable defined. Replace all instances of `example` with `node`. Do this and compile using any c++ compiler and your errors should go away. Also, why have you created a `Stack` class because you are not using it anywhere in your code. This is given that you are trying to code in cpp, because your problem tag says otherwise.

Comment: I have added C++ tag.

Comment: You might want to provide at least the first few errors. Sometimes later errors are the result of earlier ones. Also, just as an aside, you have several memory-management issues in this code.

Comment: Your Stack takes integers but the rest of your code is trying to put Node on the stack, that will not work. If you want to use std::stack then you can throw away your Stack implementation otherwise you need to rewrite Stack to handle Node instead.

Answer (score 0):

I modified you code and now it has no error during the compiling. I don't exactly understand what you want to do with this code. I used STL stack, and the class was useless.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char* name = new char[6];
    float sumary;
    int amount;
    Node(char* name, float sumary, int amount) :name(name), sumary(sumary), amount(amount)
    {
    }
    Node() {}
};

int main()
{
    int command;
    stack<Node> node;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Input command:\n 1 - add,\n 2 - delete last,\n 3 - show all,\n 4 - exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        switch (command)
        {
        case 1:
            char name[6];
            float sumary;
            int amount;
            printf("Enter name: ");
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("Enter sumary: ");
            scanf("%f", &sumary);
            printf("Enter amount: ");
            scanf("%d", &amount);
            node.push(Node(name, sumary, amount));
            break;
        case 2:
            node.pop();
            printf("The last have been deleted");
            break;
        case 3:
            while (!node.empty())
            {
                Node temp = node.top();
                node.pop();
                cout << temp.name << " " << temp.sumary << " " << temp.amount << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Wrong command...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```